# Unions and Intersections of Open Sets are Open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

Prove:

- the union of any open sets in $X$ is open in $X$
- the intersection of a finite number of open sets in $X$ is open in $X$

I could prove the first one but how do we prove the second one?

Comment: What does it mean to be open in a metric space? Can you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: If you managed to do the first one, what is difficult about the second one?

Comment: a set A subset of X is open in X if for every x in A there exist r>0 such that the opeb ball B(x,r) is subset of A @JoeManlove

Comment: @Arthur what is difficult is the word "finite" it is confusing me i did a proof in general but i didnt find a problem that stops me because of the word "finite"

Comment: @haidar Can you post your proof for the general case?

Comment: @haidar when you prove the finite case, you take $r = \min\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\}$, and then $B(x,r)$ is an open ball around $x$ contained in all $A_i$. However, in the infinite case, such an $r$ may not exist! Consider the sets $]-1/n, 1/n[$. Their intersection is $0 = [0,0]$ which is closed, yet every one set is open.

Comment: ah yes thats true in the infinite case the set may have no minimum yes good job !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be a finite collection of open sets in $X$ and let $A$ be their intersection, so that $A = \bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb N} A_i$. If the intersection is empty, then there is nothing to prove because the empty set is open (and closed) relative to any set. So assume the intersection is nonempty.

Define $r = \min\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\},$ where each $r_i$ corresponds to the open set $A_i$. Then for any $x \in A, B_r(x) \subseteq A$ is an open ball around $x$ which is fully contained in $A$, showing that $A$ is indeed open.

$A_i$ must be a $\textit{finite}$ collection of open sets because we are only able to take the minimum of a $\textit{finite}$ number of radii. The minimum of an infinite set might not exist, and the infimum might be $0$. But open balls must have a $\textit{positive}$ radius, so we cannot construct an open ball here.

Comment: What do you mean by "each $r_i$ corresponds to the open set $A_i$"?

Answer (score 2):

If the intersection is not empty, then take $x$ from this intersection. $x$ is also in every open set (say $U_1,...,U_k$) involved in the intersection, then there are positive $d_1,...,d_k$ with $B(x,d_i)\subseteq U_i$ for $i=1,...,k$. Now, take $d:=min \{d_i\}$ which is also a positive number. Then we have $B(x,d)$ is contained in the intersection, hence the result follows.

Comment: yes i did exactly like this but then why did the doctor mention "finite" in the question?
what difference does it make?

Comment: @haldar The number called $d$ here (bad choice of name, by the way, considering it's already taken) can't be 0, it has to be greater than zero. If there are infinitely many $U_i$, you cannot guarantee that that will happen.

Comment: If it is not finite, then we cannot take "minimum" trivially, say we can only have "infimum" of 1, 1/2, 1/3,..., and it would not be positive